# SSRS - Expression to count the number of dates in a colums

Tags: ssrs-2008

In SSRS,how to count the number of dates present in a column?

I am developing a report where I need to display the total number of dates where Date_of_Delivery.Value is updated in a specific month & also I need to display the same for where Date_of_Delivery.Value is Not updated.

Please insist me.

Comment: I think you are new to stack-overflow community. last time i've seen you committed the same mistake. So, please do check this link to know how to ask the question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and another link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Here is another link for markdown editing: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a count of the number of times a date is in a certain time period, you would use the **IFF** to perform the check and then **SUM** the results.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Date_of_Delivery.Value >= CDATE("01/01/2016") AND Fields!Date_of_Delivery.Value <= CDATE("01/31/2016"), 1, 0)
```

The **IFF** will check to see if the **Date of Delivery** is between two dates and return 1 if true otherwise 0. The SUM then sums up all the results.

You should probably use some **Parameters** for your date so you can just change the parameters instead of the code in the report.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Date_of_Delivery.Value >= Parameters!START_DATE.Value AND Fields!Date_of_Delivery.Value <= Parameters!END_DATE.Value, 1, 0)
```